# comparing getchar with a character returns a warning and gives me the wrong code

Tags: c, input, getchar

i'm having a problem with comparisons using getchar() and file redirection.

I have a code that resembles this:

```
char result = getchar(); // getchar returns the next char in the file
int linecount = 0;

if (result == "\n") {
    linecount++;
}
```

But I get a warning when compiling it. It says that I can't compare an int with a pointer, but from my understanding, result is a char and so is "\n", so I'm really confused. I can also use printf("%c", result") and it works fine, implying that result is a char. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? Thanks! Also, running the code, linecount will always return 0 even if the first character in the file I'm using as my input is a newline.

Comment: `"\n"` --> `'\n'`. Period.

Comment: Oh, and also `char result` --> `int result`

Comment: Indeed `getchar` returns `int` which you assign to `char` and then compare with `char*`.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: 1) `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`  2) "\n" declares a multibyte string.  The code should be comparing to the char `'\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a `char` with a `char *`, that is, a string. "" (doublequoted) values are treated as strings in C, so your code should be

```
if (result == '\n') {
    linecount++;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `strcmp` or `strncmp` with the char casted to a pointer, but that's not necessary.

Do note that the size of a char is less than an int so the conversion from a char to int doesn't make you lose anything.

Comment: _Alternatively, you could use strcmp or strncmp with the char casted to a pointer_, not really, where is the NUL terminator?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I never knew the difference between "" and '', so this was very helpful!